# plotly manually set a onesided range

Tags: javascript, plotly

In plotly the axis range can be set manually with `yaxis: {range: [0,10]}`
e.g. https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/YXbwyo.

However, how can I set only the lower limit manually to `0`, while the upper limit should autoscale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the parameters `rangemode:'tozero'` and `autorange:true` in the layout.

I modified the traces in your codepen to not include the points where x=0 and the lower limit of the range is indeed 0 while the upper limit autoscales to the largest x- and y-values.

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  y: [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  type: 'scatter'
};
var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  y: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  type: 'scatter'
};
var data = [trace1, trace2];
var layout = {
  xaxis: {rangemode: 'tozero',
         autorange: true},
  yaxis: {rangemode: 'tozero',
         autorange: true},
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {showSendToCloud: true});
```

[image]